# Optimal storage engine for simple key/value database

Tags: java, mysql, database-design, innodb

I'm trying to decide on the best engine for a database to store our game objects. I've been trying to find various information on the different table engines, but so far haven't found much that would sway me in one direction over another.

The format is simple. There is a single table with all objects in it. It has a key and a value:

```
[int64] id (index)
[blob] data (binary serialized data of varying length)
```

We first considered using the file system, but we want something with built in clustering support that could run remotely if desired, and we didn't want to write the distribution layer ourselves.

Right now, we are looking at MySql, mainly because it's free, and pretty easy to get moving forward.

**Our table will house approximately 2-5 million rows, and we need to be able to do lookups/updates/inserts in <1ms.**

The largest BLOB for a row is approximated to be about 30kb at the moment.

I've looked at InnoDB, MyISAM, and BDB, but so far, I can't seem to gather much about them other than that InnoDB and BDB support transactions, while MyISAM does not. I've used an embedded BDB in a game before, but it wasn't integrated with MySql, and was a bear to work with because it wasn't abstracted behind a server. For this same reason, it didn't have inherent clustering support.

### Summary

So, what we are looking for is:

- Clustering support/failover redundancy
- Extremely fast lookups/updates/inserts with an int64 key (<1ms)
- Transaction support

### Question

- Which is the best engine for a key/value table that will use an int64 key? Why?

I'd be grateful if someone could at least point me in the right direction. If you have a better option than MySql, that is free, and not obtuse to interface with, I'd be happy to explore other options as well.

We will be interfacing from Java.

*Please let me know how I can improve this question or be more specific! Thanks!*

Comment: You are looking for a specialized [Key-Value Store](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL#Key.E2.80.93value_stores), perhaps - it's a big list :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL probably wouldn't be considered the "best fit" for this.  [Check out this wikipedia article on databases meant to be used as key-value stores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL#Key.E2.80.93value_stores). Some of the more popular ones it mentions are:

- Apache Cassandra
- Project Voldemort
- Riak
- BigTable
- MemcacheDB
- MongoDB (though I thought this was a document store not a KV store...)
- Berkeley DB

Comment: Yes, I had read many arguments against it since I wouldn't be using it for relational data. Are you aware of any NoSql databases that satisfy clustering support, and have a decent interface for use with Java?

Comment: @crush I'm not really sure about that.  Sorry.

Comment: Maybe it's time for me to close this question, and do some more research now that I have some new direction. Thanks!